# How can I get the emulator working for my Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0?

Tags: android, samsung-mobile

I download the package from here: http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator which appears to be the emulator I'm looking for. The problem is that the instructions listed do not match with the Android SDK Manager that I currently have installed.

As such, I'm not sure how to proceed to emulate my Samsung Galaxy Note 8.0 tablet and deploy to it.

Comment: where is the problem? It will be a good thing to get more specific....

Comment: The problem is that the UI for the Android SDK manager is laid out completely differently from the one described in installing the emulator. I can't seem to adapt the current UI to the directions.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will be a solution, for now I am not able to test it myself (have no sdk by my side for now). This tutorial from Samsung is from 2011, a little bit older and not adapted to the new Android SDK or Eclipse. So maybe You have to try following:

Extract the zip file, there must be a folder "skins" and a subfolder inside "skins" named "GALAXY Tab". Copy this subfolder to You android sdk directory:

/platforms/android-9/skins/

But check at which target API You would develop, the folder "android-9" depends on which target api You need.

Now, restart Eclipse if it is open, and open Your AVD Manager. Select "New", there must be a category "skins", here You should be able to select the added Emulator and then You could build a AVD for this Galaxy Tab.

Try it, if it doesn´t work, I will try later if I am at home.